# R - select nth occurence of regex match

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr

I'm stumped on a regex pattern where I need to select the 2nd whitespace of a string. I have tried the first 5 pages of google and all I come up with is selecting everything up until the 2nd whitespace, I just want to select the 2nd whitespace itself.

This is what I have so far.

```
txt <- "the duck is yellow"
str_extract(txt,"(?:[\\w]*)(?:[\\s])(?:[\\w]*)([\\s])")
```

Another regex I tried was:

`(\w+\s\w+\s){2}`

I am just not able to find a source that explains how to get the second occurrence of a certain character. I thought something like this would be simple.

Ultimately I want to split the text into 2 columns at the second whitespace.

Comment: In just regex, it's not so bad to get the second whitespace by defining capturing groups, and use `\2` to reference the 2nd group. However, if you're using e.g., `tidyr::separate` that won't help you very much. Instead, I'd just `separate` at whitespace into 3 columns (with the `extra = "merge"`) argument, then recombine the first two columns.

Comment: Another hack would be to replace the first whitespace with a specific string that's unlikely to otherwise occur in your data (say, `"!FIRSTSPACE!"`), then separate at the 1st white space, then get back to the original by replacing the specific string with a space.

Comment: You can try to use control verb to skip the first white space without using capturing group:  [`^.*?\s(*SKIP)(*F)|\s`](https://regex101.com/r/JUnHaW/2/)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I used the tidyr::extract method below and it worked perfectly. It was nice to get some ideas to help me think outside the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To divide data into two columns splitting on second whitespace you can try using `tidyr::extract`.

```
df <- data.frame(txt = "the duck is yellow")
tidyr::extract(df, txt, c('first', 'second'), '(\\w+\\s\\w+)\\s(.*)')

#     first    second
#1 the duck is yellow
```

Or with `strcapture` using base R :

```
strcapture('(\\w+\\s\\w+)\\s(.*)', df$txt, 
           proto = list(first = character(), second = character()))
```

Answer (score 1):

To split the word at the second space, I might suggest using `sub` here:

```r
txt <- "the duck is yellow"
first <- sub("^(\\w+ \\w+).*$", "\\1", txt)
second <- sub("^\\w+ \\w+\\s*", "", txt)
first
[1] "the duck"

second
[1] "is yellow"
```

But this approach could get unwieldy if you needed to split at the nth space, buried somewhere inside the string.  For a more general approach, we can try using `strsplit`, and then piece together the terms:

```r
parts <- strsplit(txt, " ")
pos <- 2
first <- paste(parts[[1]][1:pos], collapse=" ")                        # "the duck"
second <- paste(parts[[1]][(pos+1):length(parts[[1]])], collapse=" ")  # "is yellow"
```